# Three.js mouse action

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouse

i asked yesterday about how to draw 3D objects in the browser, be able to manipulate them with the mouse and be sure that it works in every browser. Now i am using three.js and im quite happy because it actually works.

I was able to understand the basic tutorial, draw my first scene and rotate the first cube etc.

Now i want to be able to rotate the complete scene with the mouse, googled and found [this link](http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/controls/TrackballControls.js.html). Works fine in the example and i tried to copy the example. Current code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first Three.js app</title>
    <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
      <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">                      
           // Variables
           var scene, camera, controls, renderer;   
           var geometry, material, cube;            

           init();
           animate();
           render();

           function init() {
                // Scene, camera
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 500, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

                // Mouse controls
                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

             controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
             controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
             controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

             controls.noZoom = false;
             controls.noPan = false;

             controls.staticMoving = true;
             controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;  
             controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];   
             controls.addEventListener('change',test,false);

                // Renderer
                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                // Basic cube to show
                geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10,10,10);
                material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00});
                cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
                scene.add(cube);

                camera.position.z = 10;
           }

           function test() {
                alert("hi");
                render();
           } 
           function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
                controls.update();     
           }
           function render() {                
              renderer.render(scene, camera);
               //cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
               //cube.rotation.y += 0.1;
           }        
    </script>
</body>
```

But it doesn't work. The testoutput "hi" only appears once. It should appear quite often when using the mouse. What i tried to accomplish is that controls.addEventListener('change',test,false); looks if anything with the mouse changes (position, keydown etc.) and then calls a new renderframe. In the example ([Example](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html)) it somehow does what i want it to do.

What am i doing wrong here? I just want to be able to rotate the camera with mousedragging. And yes i am totally new to this. Just read about it for 2 hours now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't use the `change` event for mouse.  Look into `mousemove`, `mousedown` and how to use the `event object` to work out the direction of the mouse movement.

Comment: @ Infra Stank: There is no mousemove, mousedown etc. in the linked example. Then why does it work there?

Comment: Checkout `TrackballControls.js` .